# Docker API is always returning empty JSON even when there are images in the server

Tags: linux, docker, api, ubuntu, docker-api

When I do "docker images" in my server, there are multiple images coming up. The same when tried to access through an api "curl http://localhost:2355/images/json" returns []. Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  Have you taken any steps at all to secure the Docker socket; it's very easy to use it to root the host?

Comment: What does `docker context ls` output?

Comment: Thanks guys for responding, docker was not correctly installed on the server. I reinstalled it and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

write this command your server and look your api is expose?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl46o.png)

if you getting response like this your api not open for request

if do you want get access you must change `docker.service` file

Comment: Thanks a bunch for contributing by answering questions! However, please don't upload images of code/data/errors. There are many reasons why, and you can read some of them [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). If you could edit your answer that would be great!